# if condition and while loop doesnt work properly

Tags: python, python-2.7

th if condition doesnt stop the game, when i do more than 3 mistakes the game should stop, but actually it continues in the next level, can you please tell me what is my problem? i did also with while loop but then it doesnt print the last 2 lines, i am stuck, i tried couple combination and methods but idk what to do. appreciate your help.
thank you.

```
import random
equations=("+","-","*","/")
print "Welcome to the random math question game!"
n = 0
total_wrong_answers=0
while n < 5:
    n = n + 1
    points = 0
    print "level:" + str(n)
    q=0
    wrong_answers = 0
    if wrong_answers < 3:
    #if wrong_answers != 3:
    #while wrong_answers != 3:
    #while wrong_answers < 3:
        while q < 5:
            q=q+1
            signs=random.choice(equations[:n])
            if n<4:
                num1 = random.randint(0,10)
                num2 = random.randint(0,10)
            else:
                num1 = random.randint(0, 100)
                num2 = random.randint(0, 100)
            result=eval(str(num1)+signs+str(num2))
            print (str(num1)+signs+str(num2)),"guess the result"
            answer=(input("answer:"))
            if answer==result:
                points=points+1
                print str(result) + " Right answer.","Your points:"+str(points)
                print points * "*"
            else:
                points = points
                print "Wrong answer.","Your points:"+str(points)
                print points*"*"
                total_wrong_answers=total_wrong_answers+1
                wrong_answers=wrong_answers+1
    else:
        print "the game has finished, total wrong answers:" + str(total_wrong_answers)
        print "wrong answers in this level:" + str(wrong_answers)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're using python 2.7? Python 3 is generally preferable for new code - and for new coders - wherever possible.

Comment: @Ivc it asked to be coded on 2.7

Comment: Your code only prints the last two lines if `wrong_answers >= 3`. If the game is over at that point, your `print` statements should be outside the `while` loop, not inside an `else` inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 1):

You set `wrong_answers` to zero right before your `if wrong_answers < 3` statement. Obviously, `wrong_answer` would be always less than 3 because it's zero You must move this line

```
wrong_answers = 0
```

to other place and change the logic because this alone would not be enough.

Comment: the wrong_anwers should be reset each level, and if i put outside of level 'while loop' it will not reset

Comment: That's what I said - you have to change a logic a little bit too! I didn't say jus to put it outside of ``while``-loop.

Comment: You start a new level - set it to zero again. It's not hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question correctly, you want the game to end as soon as 3 mistakes are done.

Consider adding the condition to the `while q < 5:` part:

```
while (q < 5)and(wrong_answers<3):
```

Comment: I probably misunderstood what you are trying to acheive. Please edit your question with more specific instructions

Answer (score 0):

I think your if is in the wrong place for what you want and that you would still need to break out of the loop or exit. Something like this:

```
import random

equations = ("+", "-", "*", "/")
print "Welcome to the random math question game!"
n = 0
total_wrong_answers = 0
wrong_answers = 0
while n < 5:
    n = n + 1
    points = 0
    print "level:" + str(n)
    q = 0

    if wrong_answers < 3:
        wrong_answers = 0
        while q < 5:
            q = q + 1
            signs = random.choice(equations[:n])
            if n < 4:
                num1 = random.randint(0, 10)
                num2 = random.randint(0, 10)
            else:
                num1 = random.randint(0, 100)
                num2 = random.randint(0, 100)
            result = eval(str(num1) + signs + str(num2))
            print (str(num1) + signs + str(num2)), "guess the result"
            answer = (input("answer:"))
            if answer == result:
                points = points + 1
                print str(result) + " Right answer.", "Your points:" + str(points)
                print points * "*"
            else:
                points = points
                print "Wrong answer.", "Your points:" + str(points)
                print points * "*"
                total_wrong_answers = total_wrong_answers + 1
                wrong_answers = wrong_answers + 1
    else:
        print "the game has finished, total wrong answers:" + str(total_wrong_answers)
        print "wrong answers in this level:" + str(wrong_answers)
        exit()
```

Edited given the new info in the comments.

Comment: thank you but, the game should ask all five questions and then deside either you lost the game or u continue